# Return Pointer To Non-Modifiable Member Array C++ gcc warning

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc

I would like to return a pointer to an array owned by a class. However, I do not want to allow users to modify that data or pointer. According to how I understand things you need return a constant pointer to constant data using the following syntax.

```
const Type *const Class::Method() {
    return this->data_; 
}
```

However gcc gives the following warning when compiling.

> warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type

Why is this warning provided by gcc? What does it mean? If this is not the right syntax for what I want, what is?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to return a `std::vector<decltype(data_[0])>`?

Comment: I am working with a C interface that expects a const float*, and for performance reasons I would like to shy away from instantiating a std::vector.

Comment: Enlighten us with the formal definition of `Type` please.

Comment: The type of "Type" is float [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level `const` is ignored for built-in types. As there is a rule in C++[3.14p4]: `class and array prvalues can have cv-qualified types; other prvalues always have cv-unqualified types.`. In your case `const Type* const`, the top level `const` making the pointer `const` is ignored.

You could add `const` to the end: `const Type * Class::Method() const {...}`. This would prevent the pointer from being modified inside the member function. *However*, since the member function returns prvalue which is non-modifiable, it is not necessary to do this to prevent modification of the pointer member outside of the class (and this is also the reason why this rule exists in C++). It may be useful when you want to call the function with a constant reference to a `Class` object, etc., but for what you are doing, this doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I don't think `const Type * Class::Method() const` should be part of this answer: that might be the right thing to do but it doesn't have anything to do with what he's asking for.

Comment: (especially since his code seems to compile without error right now)

Comment: @StephenLin: I've reworded the answer to clarify (Thanks).

Answer (score 2):

The warning you get is because the final `const` is overlooked. Take it off and you're set.

You don't need to return a `const` pointer to `const` data, just a pointer to `const` data (which is `const Type*`). Just as it doesn't make sense to return a `const int`, it doesn't make sense to return a `T* const`, because as soon as the value is assigned to a new variable, that `const` is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

First const is right, the second const does not make any sense. Just look at this example:

```
const int foo();
int a = foo();
```

The fact if foo returns const int or just int does not change anything in this case. Same for Type *.

Comment: Your example does not relate to the problem.

Comment: Try to compile const int foo() { return 0; } with the same warning level and see how it is unrelated...